# Using access() in C

Tags: c, file, file-access

I am trying to use `access()` to see if a file exists; however, it is not working as expected. The current implementation is like so:

```
void checkFile(char * file)
{
     if (access(file, F_OK) != -1){
         //Do things
     }else{
         //Return an Error
     }
}
```

This is just an extract of how I am using it.  However, it always hits the `else` statement and returns an error for a file that exists. I have used absolute paths, relative paths and it is still not working.

Can you see what is going wrong?

Comment: does errno provide some information?

Comment: Could you show us value of `file`?

Comment: There is no error in the code you've posted (though you should check for `== 0` for success). Either the value of `file` is somehow wrong, or there is an error somewhere else in your program.

Comment: I have tried these methods so far for file:

   1) test.txt
   2) ./test.txt
   3) <folderpathfromroot>/test.txt

Comment: You've not shown us that the file `test.txt` exists in the current directory.  Indeed, your code is telling you that despite your expectations, the file does not exist in the current directory of the actual process. Are you using an IDE to develop this? Are you sure the IDE isn't throwing you off the track by running the program in a separate directory? You should upgrade your code into a simple MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), showing us how you call the function and using print functions in the `if` and `else` branches.

Comment: You should print the file name in the `checkFile()` function.  You should consider printing the result of [`getcwd()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html) in the main program.  And you should show us the result of `ls -l` in the correct directory.

Comment: Please try to print the error number. Some times the file may exists but the calling process does not have the specified permissions,So access will returns –1 and sets errno to EACCES

Comment: Resolved, it was due to fgets putting '\n' on the end of the string instead of '\0'

Comment: `fgets()` doesn't put the newline at the end of the string; it keeps it at the end of the line (and follows it with a null byte) assuming there is enough space for the whole line.  But yes, a filename with a newline at the end is not referencing the same file as the name without the newline at the end.